# Second Line in Matplotlib plot is inaccurate/runs all over the grid

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I'm trying to plot fantasy points from two players in every game since the start of the NBA season. 
I've created a dataframe that has the lines of every player, every night, and I want to plot every date that each have played.

The two dataframes look as such.

```
kemba[['Date','FP']]              
            Date    FP
Rk                    
260   10/23/2019   2.0
532   10/25/2019  28.0
754   10/26/2019  49.0
1390  10/30/2019  35.0
1628   11/1/2019  39.5
2178   11/5/2019  32.5
2463   11/7/2019  17.5
2800   11/9/2019  40.0
3103  11/11/2019  37.5
3410  11/13/2019  37.0
3699  11/15/2019  25.0
4001  11/17/2019  22.5
4186  11/18/2019  22.0
4494  11/20/2019   9.5
4750  11/22/2019   4.0
5637  11/27/2019  50.5
5904  11/29/2019  19.0
6193   12/1/2019  22.5
6677   12/4/2019  43.5
6975   12/6/2019  26.0
7454   12/9/2019  33.5
7769  12/11/2019  57.0
7861  12/12/2019  31.5
8614  12/18/2019  35.5
9071  12/20/2019   5.0
9289  12/22/2019  26.0
100   12/25/2019  23.0

ingram[['Date','FP']]
            Date    FP
Rk                    
22    10/22/2019  31.5
441   10/25/2019  37.5
646   10/26/2019  57.0
984   10/28/2019  41.5
1439  10/31/2019  30.0
1718   11/2/2019  10.5
1994   11/4/2019  59.0
2586   11/8/2019  30.0
2757   11/9/2019  31.5
4245  11/19/2019  30.5
4532  11/21/2019  38.5
4864  11/23/2019  40.5
5022  11/24/2019  32.5
5496  11/27/2019  22.0
5784  11/29/2019  43.0
6111   12/1/2019  31.0
6404   12/3/2019  40.0
6737   12/5/2019  27.0
7038   12/7/2019  18.0
7372   12/9/2019  38.5
7668  12/11/2019  29.0
7958  12/13/2019  38.0
8283  12/15/2019  32.5
8551  12/17/2019  24.0
8612  12/18/2019  48.0
8891  12/20/2019  30.5
102   12/23/2019  31.0
55    12/25/2019  46.5
```

The data that I've plotted is such:

```py
#  creating x & y for Ingram
ingram_fp=ingram['FP']
ingram_date=ingram['Date']

#  creating x and y for Kemmba
kemba_fp=kemba['FP']
kemba_date=kemba['Date']

fig=plt.figure()
plt.plot(kemba_date,kemba_fp,color='#FF5733',linewidth=1,marker='.',label='Walker')
plt.plot(ingram_date,ingram_fp,color='#33A7FF',marker='.',label='Ingram')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

When I do this, the link for Ingram is all over the place. Any idea on what went wrong?

This is the plot I get

[image]

Comment: Sort based on the x values before you plot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `Date` might not be formatted as a date.

Modify your code as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

#  creating x & y for Ingram
ingram_fp=ingram['FP']
ingram_date=pd.to_datetime(ingram['Date'])

#  creating x and y for Kemmba
kemba_fp=kemba['FP']
kemba_date=pd.to_datetime(kemba['Date'])
```